# Pip3 not working on Ubuntu Jammy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, python

I'm trying to install a pip3 package. When it run "pip3 install mitype", I get the following error in the terminal:

```
$ pip3 install mitype

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/trent/.local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/home/trent/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/trent/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/home/trent/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import symbol
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'symbol'
```

On Stackoverflow, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836444/no-module-named-symbol) for this seems to be to run `pip3 install --upgrade pip3 setuptools` or `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` for Python 2. However, neither of these worked for me, I still got the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: It looks like your python installation broke. Reinstalling python must fix this, I think.

Comment: Ran `sudo apt-get purge python3* && sudo apt-get install python3` and the issue persists.

Comment: Found it!! : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70837055/13611174

Comment: I tried that too, I'm still getting the error. Every pip3 command isn't working.

Comment: I've tried fully purging pip3, but the error persists. I'm lost at this point.

Comment: sorry, TL;DRs made me bad at reading things [*Sigh*]. Check the path, wrongly configured path can also cause this. BTW, I tried installing mitype, and it worked for me just fine.

Comment: Here is my path: `['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/trent/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136289/discussion-between-saaransh-garg-and-riversiderocks).

Comment: **Ubuntu 22.04 or not?** Seeing "3.10" I'd wager that you have "updated" Ubuntu's original Python (`$ python --version`  prints `Python 3.8.10` at least in 20.04.4) - Ubuntu `apt` and `apt-get` depends heavily on python being the original version. I consider the update to be a "no-no" for anyone but the most initiated (knowledgeable) Ubuntu user.

Comment: File a bug here https://github.com/Mithil467/mitype/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc